# Does Facebook Live or Youtube Live allow third party build mobile apps on top of them?

Tags: youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api, facebook-live-api

Imagine the following scenario. I want to build an iPhone app that support a specific type of live streaming (and to build my own user bases over time).

Can my app use Facebook Live api to create an ingress point (for uploading) and use the egress point to display the live stream in my app?

This idea is basically using Facebook Live as a utility (i.e., I outsource the live video delivery development to Facebook) -- I don't see any value this application may bring to Facebook though.

Does Facebook Live support it?

Does Youtube Live support the above idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not YouTube's or Facebook's customer service.

Answer (score 3):

Youtube should allow live streaming from mobile apps, however Facebook does not.
[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started) (Youtube Live API Intro) may help you.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Facebook doesn't allow mobile apps to stream to Facebook Live.  https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI

Comment: Right you are. Edited my answer